# WatchKit: Altimeter on watch returns the altitude of iPhone (not the watch)

Tags: ios, watch, core-motion

I want to get the relative altitude change of the watch. When watch is connected to the iPhone, the watch returns the relative altitude of the iPhone. How can I force the watch to return its own altitude even when the iPhone is connected to it.

Here is my code:

```
        func startAltimeter() {
        if CMAltimeter.isRelativeAltitudeAvailable() {
            switch CMAltimeter.authorizationStatus() {
             case .notDetermined: // Handle state before user prompt
             print("*******************Motion permission is not determined")
             case .restricted: // Handle system-wide restriction
                fatalError("Authorization restricted!")
            case .denied: // Handle user denied state
                fatalError("Authorization denied!")
            case .authorized: // Ready to go!
                let _ = print("Authorized!")
            @unknown default:
                fatalError("Unknown Authorization Status")
            }
            self.altimeter.startRelativeAltitudeUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) {(data,error) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.relativeAlt = data?.relativeAltitude.doubleValue ?? 0.0
                    print("relative alttitude = \(self.relativeAlt) m")
                }
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.relativeAlt = -99
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `relativeAltitude.doubleValue` uses the iPhone barometer if the iPhone is paired with the Watch. To get the altitude from the watch sensor directly, you must use the absolute altitude (`altitude` property).

It's not documented and it doesn't make sense, but that's how it works.